# $\mathbb{Z}[x] / I$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm learning abstract algebra, specifically ring theory, and need help to understand the remark given in the solution of the following exercise:

Let the ideal $I$ be defined as $I = \{f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x] \, \text{such that} \, 2 \, | \, f(0)\}$. Determine $\mathbb{Z}[x] / I$.

Here's a quick solution (my problem is really on the last remark):

We have $\mathbb{Z}[x] / I = \{h(x)+ I : h(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]\}$ where $h(x) = a_nx^n + \ldots + a_1x + a_0$.

First case: $a_0 = 2k, k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then

$$h(x) + I  = (a_nx^n + \ldots + a_1x + 2k) + I = I.$$

Second case: $a_0 = 2k+1, k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then

$$h(x) + I  = (a_nx^n + \ldots + a_1x + 2k +1) + I = ((a_nx^n + \ldots + a_1x + 2k ) + I) + (1 + I)$$ $$= I + (1 + I) = (1 + I).$$

Therefore, $\mathbb{Z}[x] / I = \{I, 1+I\}$.

**Remark** : note that $\mathbb{Z}[x] / I \simeq \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}[x] / I$ is a field.

I understand that, since the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}[x] / I$ has two elements, it is isomorphic to the field $\mathbb{Z}_2$ (since $p = 2$ is prime). What I don't understand is why $\mathbb{Z}[x] / I$ is a field?

I also concluded that (correct me if I'm wrong), since $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a commutative ring with identity and $\mathbb{Z}[x] / I$ is a field, then $I$ is in fact a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.  But it is unclear to me why $\mathbb{Z}[x] / I$ is a field.

Comment: If you see why it's isomorphic to the field $\mathbb{Z}_2$, then you see why it's a field. Anything isomorphic to a field, *is* a field, because isomorphism is algebraic equivalence.

Comment: You undertstand that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/I$ is isomorphic to a field but you don't understand why does it follow from that the $\mathbb{Z}[x]/I$ *is* a field. Is that it?

Comment: What kind of a reason are you looking for? As you said, any ring with two elements is a field.

Comment: "But it is unclear to me why it is a field" - trivial answer: because it is $\mathbb{F}_2$, which is a field. So it is a field.

Comment: Indeed $I = (2,x)$ so $ \mathbb{Z}[x]/I =  \mathbb{Z}[x]/(2,x) =  \mathbb{Z}/(2)[x] /(x) \cong \mathbb{Z}/(2) = \mathbb{F}_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotient ring $\mathbb Z[X]/I$ is isomorphic to a field. Now, prove that any ring isomorphic to a field is a field. (Hint: the image/pre-image of the inverse gives you the inverse).